# send_file problems in Rails3 DEVELOPMENT mode

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, x-sendfile

I've seen the issues here about send_file and apache/nginx and all point to this line in production.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

Well and good, but what about development? I am on development right now and pasting the url to my browser gets me a zip file with 0 bytes.

It is also worth noting that this has been working perfectly before, both in Mac and Windows(1.8.7 MRI for both - windows using apache with thin). We switched to JRuby and all hell broke loose. Now even if I switch to my mri gemset(using rvm) I still get the 0 byte zip file.

What could be the problem and how should I go about debugging and solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it after a painstaking rewind of all my commits. Apparently the gem rack-webconsole craps out send_file for some reason. I took it out of my Gemfile and everything worked again.